# web-mode django custom block indentions

Tags: web-mode

The official style of the project I'm working on is to indent after template control statements. We're using jinja2 templates with altered open/closing tags too...

```
 <ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
       <li>...</li>
    {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

Some with if statements, elses, etc.

Is there a way to configure webmode to do this?

Comment: web-mode.el should handle like this by default. Are you sure the good template engine is associated with your template ? You can check this with ```web-mode-debug```

Comment: maybe https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/669 ?